# What difference does adding sudo infront of guix system reconfigure make?

Tags: guixsd

Both seems to run just fine? Are there different systems for my normal user and if I run the command as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is only one system. Both will run fine until the very end when the symbolic link pointing at the current version of the system configuration is modified. A normal user is not allowed to modify this symlink and the upgrade will fail, so run the command with sudo.